# Database application.yml for Spring boot from applications.properties

Tags: spring, spring-boot, database-connection

I've got a working Spring Boot Application that connects to a Postgres database. I've got the project set up with an application.properties file, but would like to make the switch over to an application.yml file. However when I make the switch, my application errors out while attempting to connect to the db.

Original applications.properties file:

```
spring.jpa.database=POSTGRESQL
spring.datasource.platform=postgres
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
spring.database.driverClassName=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/mydb
spring.datasource.username=foo
spring.datasource.password=bar
```

And Here's what I've got so far in the application.yml file:

```
spring.jpa:
  database: POSTGRESQL
  hibernate.ddl-auto: create-drop
  show-sql: true

spring.datasource:
  platform: postgres
  driverClassName: org.postgresql.Driver
  url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/mydb
  username: foo
  password: bar
```

Am I missing something in the translation between file types?

Answer (score 66):

You need to treat each `.` character in property names as levels in the `yaml` file:

```
spring:
  jpa:
    database: POSTGRESQL
    show-sql: true
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: create-drop
  datasource:
    platform: postgres
    url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/mydb
    username: foo
    password: bar
    driverClassName: org.postgresql.Driver
```

**EDIT**: edits have been suggested, thanks for that. The `driverClassName` property actually should be under `spring.datasource`. However, the purpose of this answer was to show how a `properties` file is converted into `yaml` format. So I have changed the `driverClassName` property to be at the right path, that is not part of the transformation from `properties` to `yaml`.

Answer (score 19):

Please upvote the other answer (Z0lt@n's answer)

But pasting here for future readers... a sql server version.

```
spring:
  jpa:
    show-sql: true
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: update
    properties:
      hibernate.jdbc.batch_size: 20
      hibernate.cache.use_query_cache: false
      hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache: false
      hibernate.cache.use_structured_entries: false
      hibernate.cache.use_minimal_puts: false
  datasource:
    #SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL environment variable will be something like -> jdbc:sqlserver://MySqlServer\\MyInstance:1433;DatabaseName=MyDbName;
    url: ${SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL}
    username: ${SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME}
    password: ${SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD}
    driverClassName: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
```

and maven entry

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
        <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>7.0.0.jre8</version>
    </dependency>
```

APPEND

This seems to be the "standard" name for the driverClassName.

```
SPRING_DATASOURCE_DRIVER-CLASS-NAME
```

And of course, in my example, you would use the value of:

```
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
```

NOW, some spring, springboot, environment variable voodoo alert.

Sometimes, when specifying the environment variable...for some command lines items, I would have to change the hyphens and make them underscores.
(aka, "SPRING_DATASOURCE_DRIVER-CLASS-NAME" vs "SPRING_DATASOURCE_DRIVER_CLASS_NAME"

below the -e generically represents "passing environment variable values via the command line"

```
MyCommandLineProgram.exe -e SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL="jdbc:sqlserver://myServerName:1433;DatabaseName=MyDB;" -e SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME="myUserName" -e SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD="myPassword" -e SPRING_DATASOURCE_DRIVER_CLASS_NAME="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
```

There's some voodoo for you.

Those interested in the logging (logback.xml) issue, maybe want to find my answer here as well:

[Spring Boot Logback DB Appender Properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33186668/spring-boot-logback-db-appender-properties)

Comment: so just specifying SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL (and others) env var is not enough for Datasource? you need to explicitly set spring.jpa.datasource.url parameters?

Comment: All the others probably have defaults.  ddl-auto is the one I would be explicit about since it can be dangerous in production environment.

Answer (score 12):

**application.yml** file for ***postgresql***

### Spring DATASOURCE (DataSourceAutoConfiguration & DataSourceProperties)

```
spring:
  datasource:
    driver-class-name: org.postgresql.Driver
    username: postgres
    password: root
    url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost/postgres
    platform: postgres
    initialization-mode: always
    continue-on-error: true
  jpa:
    show-sql: true
    generate-ddl: true
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: create
    database: postgresql
```

Answer (score 0):

```
server:
  port: 1111  
spring:
    application:
      name: client-one 
    datasource:
     password: postgres
     url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres?currentSchema=education
     username: postgres
    jpa:
     hibernate:
      ddl-auto: update
     properties:
      hibernate:
        dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
     show-sql: true
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

File `application.yml`

```yaml
server:
    port: 1234
spring:
    application:
        name: foo
    datasource:
        url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/foo
        password: postgres
        username: postgres
    jpa:
        hibernate:
            ddl-auto: update
        properties:
            hibernate:
                dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
        show-sql: true
```

Test with PostgreSQL 15.3 , JDK 20, Spring Boot 3.1.0 .