# Spring boot 2 does not work with Postgres

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa

I have a Spring Boot JPA application with spring boot 2.0.3.RELEASE and connects to PostgreSQL, when i run the application i get the error message below:

```
Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and no embedded datasource could be configured.
Reason: Failed to determine a suitable driver class
```

Database connection properties:

```
spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/testS
    username: postgres
    password: postgres123
    driver-class-name: org.postgresql.Driver
```

Dependencies:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Stacktrace:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties$DataSourceBeanCreationException: Failed to determine a suitable driver class
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Share stacktrace it will be helpful

Comment: @GauravSrivastav done

Comment: try using attribute inside datasource: `dataSourceClassName=org.postgresql.ds.PGSimpleDataSource`

Comment: Take a look at this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33324144/967808

Comment: it still the same problem

Comment: The error message `Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified` indicates that your `application.yml` file isn't read at all

Answer (score 0):

You just changed the dependency as below. Include version and scope  element in dependency.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
    <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
    <version>9.1-901.jdbc4</version>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: it still the same problem

Comment: What your's postgres version, jar should be compatible to it. One more thing check  is the dependency download or not.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem when using spring profiles in my application.yml.
I only defined the spring.datasource.* properties in the profile's section of the yaml.
However, when I moved those properties to the MAIN section (i.e. the default profile), the problem disappeared.