# Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a Spring Boot application and I am trying to use Postgres but the applications fails to start each time.
Here is the stack trace:

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_141\bin\java.exe" "-javaagent:D:\Programs\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2018.2.1\lib\idea_rt.jar=55780:D:\Programs\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2018.2.1\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_141\jre\lib\charsets.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_141\jre\lib\deploy.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_141\jre\lib\ext\access-bridge-64.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_141\jre\lib\ext\cldrdata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_141\jre\lib\ext\dnsns.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_141\jre\lib\ext\jaccess.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_141\jre\lib\ext\jfxrt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_141\jre\lib\ext\localedata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_141\jre\lib\ext\nashorn.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_141\jre\lib\ext\sunec.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_141\jre\lib\ext\sunjce_provider.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_141\jre\lib\ext\sunmscapi.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_141\jre\lib\ext\sunpkcs11.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_141\jre\lib\ext\zipfs.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_141\jre\lib\javaws.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_141\jre\lib\jce.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_141\jre\lib\jfr.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_141\jre\lib\jfxswt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_141\jre\lib\jsse.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_141\jre\lib\management-agent.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_141\jre\lib\plugin.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_141\jre\lib\resources.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_141\jre\lib\rt.jar;D:\main\gdrive\core\fooapp\api-module\target\classes;D:\main\gdrive\core\fooapp\commons-module\target\classes;C:\Users\andromeda\.m2\repository\javax\validation\validation-api\2.0.1.Final\validation-api-2.0.1.Final.jar;C:\Users\andromeda\.m2\repository\org\postgresql\postgresql\42.2.1\postgresql-42.2.1.jar;C:\Users\andromeda\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-data-jpa\2.0.0.RELEASE\spring-boot-starter-data-jpa-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\andromeda\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-aop\2.0.0.RELEASE\spring-boot-starter-aop-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\andromeda\.m2\repository\org\aspectj\aspectjweaver\1.8.13\aspectjweaver-1.8.13.jar;C:\Users\andromeda\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-jdbc\2.0.0.RELEASE\spring-boot-starter-jdbc-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\andromeda\.m2\repository\com\zaxxer\HikariCP\2.7.8\HikariCP-2.7.8.jar;C:\Users\andromeda\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-jdbc\5.0.4.RELEASE\spring-jdbc-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\andromeda\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\hibernate-core\5.2.14.Final\hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar;C:\Users\andromeda\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\javax\persistence\hibernate-jpa-2.1-api\1.0.0.Final\hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.0.Final.jar;C:\Users\andromeda\.m2\repository\org\javassist\javassist\3.22.0-GA\javassist-3.22.0-GA.jar;C:\Users\andromeda\.m2\repository\antlr\antlr\2.7.7\antlr-2.7.7.jar;C:\Users\andromeda\.m2\repository\org\jboss\jandex\2.0.3.Final\jandex-2.0.3.Final.jar;C:\Users\andromeda\.m2\repository\dom4j\dom4j\1.6.1\dom4j-1.6.1.jar;C:\Users\andromeda\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\common\hibernate-commons-annotations\5.0.1.Final\hibernate-commons-annotations-5.0.1.Final.jar;C:\Users\andromeda\.m2\repository\javax\transaction\javax.transaction-api\1.2\javax.transaction-api-1.2.jar;C:\Users\andromeda\.m2\repository\org\springframework\data\spring-data-jpa\2.0.5.RELEASE\spring-data-jpa-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\andromeda\.m2\repository\org\springframework\data\spring-data-commons\2.0.5.RELEASE\spring-data-commons-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\andromeda\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-orm\5.0.4.RELEASE\spring-orm-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\andromeda\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-tx\5.0.4.RELEASE\spring-tx-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\andromeda\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-aspects\5.0.4.RELEASE\spring-aspects-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\andromeda\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-mail\2.0.0.RELEASE\spring-boot-starter-mail-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\andromeda\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-context\5.0.4.RELEASE\spring-context-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\andromeda\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-context-support\5.0.4.RELEASE\spring-context-support-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\andromeda\.m2\repository\com\sun\mail\javax.mail\1.6.1\javax.mail-1.6.1.jar;C:\Users\andromeda\.m2\repository\javax\activation\activation\1.1\activation-1.1.jar;C:\Users\andromeda\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-freemarker\2.0.0.RELEASE\spring-boot-starter-freemarker-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\andromeda\.m2\repository\org\freemarker\freemarker\2.3.27-incubating\freemarker-2.3.27-incubating.jar;C:\Users\andromeda\.m2\repository\commons-validator\commons-validator\1.6\commons-validator-1.6.jar;C:\Users\andromeda\.m2\repository\commons-beanutils\commons-beanutils\1.9.2\commons-beanutils-1.9.2.jar;C:\Users\andromeda\.m2\repository\commons-digester\commons-digester\1.8.1\commons-digester-1.8.1.jar;C:\Users\andromeda\.m2\repository\commons-logging\commons-logging\1.2\commons-logging-1.2.jar;C:\Users\andromeda\.m2\repository\commons-collections\commons-collections\3.2.2\commons-collections-3.2.2.jar;C:\Users\andromeda\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-amqp\2.0.0.RELEASE\spring-boot-starter-amqp-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\andromeda\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-messaging\5.0.4.RELEASE\spring-messaging-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\andromeda\.m2\repository\org\springframework\amqp\spring-rabbit\2.0.2.RELEASE\spring-rabbit-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\andromeda\.m2\repository\org\springframework\amqp\spring-amqp\2.0.2.RELEASE\spring-amqp-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\andromeda\.m2\repository\com\rabbitmq\amqp-client\5.1.2\amqp-client-5.1.2.jar;C:\Users\andromeda\.m2\repository\com\rabbitmq\http-client\1.3.1.RELEASE\http-client-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\andromeda\.m2\repository\org\apache\httpcomponents\httpclient\4.5.5\httpclient-4.5.5.jar;C:\Users\andromeda\.m2\repository\org\apache\httpcomponents\httpcore\4.4.9\httpcore-4.4.9.jar;C:\Users\andromeda\.m2\repository\org\springframework\retry\spring-retry\1.2.2.RELEASE\spring-retry-1.2.2.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\andromeda\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-data-redis\2.0.0.RELEASE\spring-boot-starter-data-redis-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\andromeda\.m2\repository\org\springframework\data\spring-data-redis\2.0.5.RELEASE\spring-data-redis-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\andromeda\.m2\repository\org\springframework\data\spring-data-keyvalue\2.0.5.RELEASE\spring-data-keyvalue-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\andromeda\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-oxm\5.0.4.RELEASE\spring-oxm-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\andromeda\.m2\repository\redis\clients\jedis\2.9.0\jedis-2.9.0.jar;C:\Users\andromeda\.m2\repository\org\apache\commons\commons-pool2\2.5.0\commons-pool2-2.5.0.jar;C:\Users\andromeda\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-web\2.0.0.RELEASE\spring-boot-starter-web-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\andromeda\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-json\2.0.0.RELEASE\spring-boot-starter-json-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\andromeda\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\datatype\jackson-datatype-jdk8\2.9.4\jackson-datatype-jdk8-2.9.4.jar;C:\Users\andromeda\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\datatype\jackson-datatype-jsr310\2.9.4\jackson-datatype-jsr310-2.9.4.jar;C:\Users\andromeda\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\module\jackson-module-parameter-names\2.9.4\jackson-module-parameter-names-2.9.4.jar;C:\Users\andromeda\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-tomcat\2.0.0.RELEASE\spring-boot-starter-tomcat-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\andromeda\.m2\repository\org\apache\tomcat\embed\tomcat-embed-core\8.5.28\tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar;C:\Users\andromeda\.m2\repository\org\apache\tomcat\embed\tomcat-embed-el\8.5.28\tomcat-embed-el-8.5.28.jar;C:\Users\andromeda\.m2\repository\org\apache\tomcat\embed\tomcat-embed-websocket\8.5.28\tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.28.jar;C:\Users\andromeda\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\validator\hibernate-validator\6.0.7.Final\hibernate-validator-6.0.7.Final.jar;C:\Users\andromeda\.m2\repository\org\jboss\logging\jboss-logging\3.3.2.Final\jboss-logging-3.3.2.Final.jar;C:\Users\andromeda\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-web\5.0.4.RELEASE\spring-web-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\andromeda\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-beans\5.0.4.RELEASE\spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\andromeda\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-webmvc\5.0.4.RELEASE\spring-webmvc-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\andromeda\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-expression\5.0.4.RELEASE\spring-expression-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\andromeda\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-security\2.0.0.RELEASE\spring-boot-starter-security-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\andromeda\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-aop\5.0.4.RELEASE\spring-aop-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\andromeda\.m2\repository\org\springframework\security\spring-security-config\5.0.3.RELEASE\spring-security-config-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\andromeda\.m2\repository\org\springframework\security\spring-security-web\5.0.3.RELEASE\spring-security-web-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\andromeda\.m2\repository\org\springframework\security\spring-security-core\5.0.3.RELEASE\spring-security-core-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\andromeda\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-core\5.0.4.RELEASE\spring-core-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\andromeda\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-jcl\5.0.4.RELEASE\spring-jcl-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\andromeda\.m2\repository\net\bytebuddy\byte-buddy\1.7.10\byte-buddy-1.7.10.jar;C:\Users\andromeda\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\dataformat\jackson-dataformat-yaml\2.9.4\jackson-dataformat-yaml-2.9.4.jar;C:\Users\andromeda\.m2\repository\org\yaml\snakeyaml\1.19\snakeyaml-1.19.jar;C:\Users\andromeda\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-core\2.9.4\jackson-core-2.9.4.jar;C:\Users\andromeda\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-databind\2.9.4\jackson-databind-2.9.4.jar;C:\Users\andromeda\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-annotations\2.9.0\jackson-annotations-2.9.0.jar;C:\Users\andromeda\.m2\repository\io\jsonwebtoken\jjwt\0.9.0\jjwt-0.9.0.jar;C:\Users\andromeda\.m2\repository\io\springfox\springfox-swagger2\2.7.0\springfox-swagger2-2.7.0.jar;C:\Users\andromeda\.m2\repository\io\swagger\swagger-annotations\1.5.13\swagger-annotations-1.5.13.jar;C:\Users\andromeda\.m2\repository\io\swagger\swagger-models\1.5.13\swagger-models-1.5.13.jar;C:\Users\andromeda\.m2\repository\io\springfox\springfox-spi\2.7.0\springfox-spi-2.7.0.jar;C:\Users\andromeda\.m2\repository\io\springfox\springfox-core\2.7.0\springfox-core-2.7.0.jar;C:\Users\andromeda\.m2\repository\io\springfox\springfox-schema\2.7.0\springfox-schema-2.7.0.jar;C:\Users\andromeda\.m2\repository\io\springfox\springfox-swagger-common\2.7.0\springfox-swagger-common-2.7.0.jar;C:\Users\andromeda\.m2\repository\io\springfox\springfox-spring-web\2.7.0\springfox-spring-web-2.7.0.jar;C:\Users\andromeda\.m2\repository\org\reflections\reflections\0.9.11\reflections-0.9.11.jar;C:\Users\andromeda\.m2\repository\com\google\guava\guava\18.0\guava-18.0.jar;C:\Users\andromeda\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\classmate\1.3.4\classmate-1.3.4.jar;C:\Users\andromeda\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\slf4j-api\1.7.25\slf4j-api-1.7.25.jar;C:\Users\andromeda\.m2\repository\org\springframework\plugin\spring-plugin-core\1.2.0.RELEASE\spring-plugin-core-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\andromeda\.m2\repository\org\springframework\plugin\spring-plugin-metadata\1.2.0.RELEASE\spring-plugin-metadata-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\andromeda\.m2\repository\org\mapstruct\mapstruct\1.1.0.Final\mapstruct-1.1.0.Final.jar;C:\Users\andromeda\.m2\repository\io\springfox\springfox-swagger-ui\2.7.0\springfox-swagger-ui-2.7.0.jar;C:\Users\andromeda\.m2\repository\com\chargebee\chargebee-java\2.6.0\chargebee-java-2.6.0.jar;C:\Users\andromeda\.m2\repository\org\json\json\20090211\json-20090211.jar;C:\Users\andromeda\.m2\repository\commons-codec\commons-codec\1.11\commons-codec-1.11.jar;C:\Users\andromeda\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter\2.0.0.RELEASE\spring-boot-starter-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\andromeda\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot\2.0.0.RELEASE\spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\andromeda\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-autoconfigure\2.0.0.RELEASE\spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\andromeda\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-logging\2.0.0.RELEASE\spring-boot-starter-logging-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\andromeda\.m2\repository\ch\qos\logback\logback-classic\1.2.3\logback-classic-1.2.3.jar;C:\Users\andromeda\.m2\repository\ch\qos\logback\logback-core\1.2.3\logback-core-1.2.3.jar;C:\Users\andromeda\.m2\repository\org\apache\logging\log4j\log4j-to-slf4j\2.10.0\log4j-to-slf4j-2.10.0.jar;C:\Users\andromeda\.m2\repository\org\apache\logging\log4j\log4j-api\2.10.0\log4j-api-2.10.0.jar;C:\Users\andromeda\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\jul-to-slf4j\1.7.25\jul-to-slf4j-1.7.25.jar;C:\Users\andromeda\.m2\repository\javax\annotation\javax.annotation-api\1.3.2\javax.annotation-api-1.3.2.jar;C:\Users\andromeda\.m2\repository\commons-lang\commons-lang\2.6\commons-lang-2.6.jar" com.fooapp.api.ApiMain

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.0.0.RELEASE)

2018-10-17 00:52:38.255  INFO 16916 --- [           main] com.fooapp.api.ApiMain             : Starting ApiMain on andromeda with PID 16916 (D:\main\gdrive\core\fooapp\api-module\target\classes started by kaustubh in D:\main\gdrive\core\fooapp)
2018-10-17 00:52:38.258  INFO 16916 --- [           main] com.fooapp.api.ApiMain             : The following profiles are active: development
2018-10-17 00:52:38.367  INFO 16916 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext@28f2a10f: startup date [Wed Oct 17 00:52:38 IST 2018]; root of context hierarchy
2018-10-17 00:52:40.215  INFO 16916 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Multiple Spring Data modules found, entering strict repository configuration mode!
2018-10-17 00:52:40.549  INFO 16916 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Overriding bean definition for bean 'rabbitTemplate' with a different definition: replacing [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=rabbitMQConfig; factoryMethodName=rabbitTemplate; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [com/fooapp/commons/RabbitMQConfig.class]] with [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.amqp.RabbitAutoConfiguration$RabbitTemplateConfiguration; factoryMethodName=rabbitTemplate; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/amqp/RabbitAutoConfiguration$RabbitTemplateConfiguration.class]]
2018-10-17 00:52:40.601  INFO 16916 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Multiple Spring Data modules found, entering strict repository configuration mode!
2018-10-17 00:52:41.180  INFO 16916 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.annotation.RabbitBootstrapConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.annotation.RabbitBootstrapConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$63d9e2b9] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2018-10-17 00:52:41.429  INFO 16916 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$9d6e248b] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2018-10-17 00:52:42.226  INFO 16916 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2018-10-17 00:52:42.274  INFO 16916 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2018-10-17 00:52:42.275  INFO 16916 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.28
2018-10-17 00:52:42.290  INFO 16916 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener   : The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: [C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_141\bin;C:\WINDOWS\Sun\Java\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Resource Kits\Tools\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\Scripts\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft MPI\Bin\;C:\Program Files\ConEmu\ConEmu\Scripts;C:\Program Files\ConEmu;C:\Program Files\ConEmu\ConEmu;C:\Python36\Scripts\;C:\Python36\;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_141\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Boxcryptor\bin\;C:\Users\andromeda\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\andromeda\.lein\bin;C:\Users\andromeda\AppData\Local\Programs\Fiddler;C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.4\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\GTK2-Runtime\bin;C:\Program Files\Mercurial;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\;D:\Programs\Git\cmd;D:\Programs\Git\mingw64\bin;D:\Programs\Git\usr\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Windows Performance Toolkit\;D:\Programs\Calibre2\;C:\Program Files (x86)\sbt\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\scala\bin;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Utilities\;D:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Pandoc\;D:\Programs\PostgreSQL\9.5\bin;C:\influxdb-1.6.1_windows_amd64;C:\SysinternalsSuite;C:\nssm-2.24-101-g897c7ad\win64;C:\Users\andromeda\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\andromeda\.lein\bin;C:\Users\andromeda\AppData\Local\Programs\Fiddler;C:\Program Files\Mercurial\;C:\Users\andromeda\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;.]
2018-10-17 00:52:42.476  INFO 16916 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2018-10-17 00:52:42.476  INFO 16916 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 4116 ms
2018-10-17 00:52:42.709  INFO 16916 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
2018-10-17 00:52:42.709  INFO 16916 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
2018-10-17 00:52:42.709  INFO 16916 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'httpPutFormContentFilter' to: [/*]
2018-10-17 00:52:42.710  INFO 16916 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'requestContextFilter' to: [/*]
2018-10-17 00:52:42.710  INFO 16916 --- [ost-startStop-1] .s.DelegatingFilterProxyRegistrationBean : Mapping filter: 'springSecurityFilterChain' to: [/*]
2018-10-17 00:52:42.710  INFO 16916 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean  : Servlet dispatcherServlet mapped to [/]
2018-10-17 00:52:42.960  INFO 16916 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2018-10-17 00:52:43.104  INFO 16916 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2018-10-17 00:52:43.178  INFO 16916 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Building JPA container EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2018-10-17 00:52:43.205  INFO 16916 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: default
    ...]
2018-10-17 00:52:43.326  INFO 16916 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.2.14.Final}
2018-10-17 00:52:43.328  INFO 16916 --- [           main] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
2018-10-17 00:52:43.379  INFO 16916 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.1.Final}
2018-10-17 00:52:43.594  INFO 16916 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
2018-10-17 00:52:43.739  INFO 16916 --- [           main] o.h.e.j.e.i.LobCreatorBuilderImpl        : HHH000421: Disabling contextual LOB creation as hibernate.jdbc.lob.non_contextual_creation is true
2018-10-17 00:52:43.741  INFO 16916 --- [           main] org.hibernate.type.BasicTypeRegistry     : HHH000270: Type registration [java.util.UUID] overrides previous : org.hibernate.type.UUIDBinaryType@108e9837
2018-10-17 00:52:44.111  WARN 16916 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
2018-10-17 00:52:44.111  INFO 16916 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2018-10-17 00:52:44.123  INFO 16916 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
2018-10-17 00:52:44.126  INFO 16916 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]

Process finished with exit code 1
```

And also here is the relevant part of the configuration file:

```
spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost/mydatabase?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true
    username: postgres
    password: mypassword
    driver-class-name: org.postgresql.Driver

  jpa:
    show-sql: true
    properties:
      hibernate:
        jdbc:
          lob:
            non_contextual_creation: true
        dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: create
```

Some people on different questions have mentioned that this error can happen if the database doesn't exist prior to execution, so I created the database manually but I still get this error.

**EDIT: Here is the TRACE log of app. As there is too much text, I have uploaded it as a file:**
https://ufile.io/zuk69

Comment: check your DB properties if anything missing you will see this error.

Comment: I have posted the part of the db configuration, I still can't see what I am missing. This is pretty much a standard config.

Comment: Change your loglevel to DEBUG to see what is happening. Should be easy to spot what is going on then.

Comment: Did you add starter data jpa dependency?

Comment: Might be you are facing this issue because you missed Port number in your Yaml config... It should be url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/mydatabase?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true

Comment: I have now added the port, also added DEBUG, which I cannot print here becaues of character limitations. No change. And DEBUG log shows just this error being created after several lines of hiberante mapping the classes schema(no error there)

Comment: Just curious to know...whether your app working properly with application.properties ? You can you once take a look at this question and try the yaml settings same as (this)[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33323837/database-application-yml-for-spring-boot-from-applications-properties] question. Close everthing and restart again.

Comment: If DEBUG won't fit here anyway, set the thing on TRACE, then zip@upload it somewhere. I expect to see some indication of trying to connect somewhere, or failing to find config, etc...

Comment: @GergelyBacso I have done that now. Edited the question with link.

Comment: Ok, even TRACE log did not help. This is getting out of hand... Next thing I would place an Exception breakpoint for the known `PersistenceException`, see what could be behind it.

Comment: Did you add Spring boot jpa-starter?

Comment: Ofcourse, yes I added it.

Comment: Could you please show me your pom, main class and project structure

Answer (score 2):

Could you try to change your yaml file to

```
spring:
    jpa:
        show-sql: true
        hibernate:
          ddl-auto: create-drop
        database: postgresql
        database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
    datasource:
        url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/mydatabase?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true
        username: postgres
        password: mypassword    
        driver-class-name: org.postgresql.Driver
```

> Fix Postgres JPA Error (Method
>   org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.createClob() is not yet implemented).

You would need to add this to your application properties:
`spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.lob.non_contextual_creation=true`

Comment: I have included the config in the question and as its clear, I have included the non_centextual_creation property there.

Answer (score 0):

It can be related to bad @annotations, did you check your source code, and Hibernate annotations, likes?

```
@OneToOne
@ManyToOne
```

And its coherence with your Database structure?