# Hibernate/Spring framework: path of the database in a configuration file

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, sqlite, spring-boot

I am trying to write a simple **Hibernate** application and I want the SQLite database location to be changed according to an application **configuration file**.

What I was trying to do was therefore retrieving the path of the database from a text file in the project and putting it inside `dbLocation`, then running the following piece of code:

```
Configuration config = new Configuration();
config.setProperty("hibernate.connection.url", "jdbc:sqlite:" + dbLocation);
```

Is there a better and more "standard" way to do so? I'm using **Spring Boot** for my application and I just realized there's afile called `application.properties`. May I use this one maybe? I'm pretty new to both Hibernate and the Spring framework.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Database application.yml for Spring boot from applications.properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33323837/database-application-yml-for-spring-boot-from-applications-properties)

Comment: You can use either .props or .yml for your configuration. Spring Boot will also split between environments so you can potentially use local/dev/qa/prod files selected at start-up time.

Answer (score 0):

In Spring Boot application properties you can externalize your application properties so they are configured/managed outside your application source code.

Once a property is defined in application.properties you can use SpringBoot built-in feature to access the values

```
@Configuration 
public class ApplicationProperty {

@Value("${prop}")
private String prop;
```

Answer (score 0):

With Spring Boot another way is to use [@ConfigurationProperties](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/context/properties/ConfigurationProperties.html).

Example from the documentation can be found [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-external-config-java-bean-binding)

A comparison between @ConfigurationProperties and @Value annotation from the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-external-config-vs-value)

```
Feature          @ConfigurationProperties   @Value

Relaxed binding      Yes                     No
Meta-data support    Yes                     No
SpEL evaluation      No                      Yes
```