# How to get spring jpa to create relation/table automatically?

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, hibernate

I'm trying to get Spring to generate the table for my entity class. I'm not sure what I'm missing, it's my first time using a containerized db.

Here is my `application.yml` file:

```
spring.datasource:
  url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:8300/fishgame
  username: admin
  password: admin
  driver-class-name: org.postgresql.Driver
jpa:
  show-sql: true
  hibernate:
    ddl-auto: create
  generate-ddl: true
  database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
```

My `docker-compose` file:

```
version: "3.8"
services:
  database:
    image: "postgres:13"
    ports:
    - "8300:5432"
    volumes:
      - /tmp/db:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=admin
      - POSTGRES_USER=admin
      - POSTGRES_DB=fishgame
```

My entity class:

```
@Data
@Entity
@Builder
@Table(name = "fishes")
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Fish  extends BaseEntity {

    private Species species;
    /**
     * Pixel percentage / second ?
     */
    private double speed;
    @Embedded
    private Position position;

}
```

When I try to save an `Fish` entity I get the following error:

> Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception
> is org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException:
> could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is
> org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute
> statement] with root cause
>
> org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation "fishes" does not
> exist   Position: 13
> at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2553)
> ~[postgresql-42.2.18.jar:42.2.18]
> at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2285)
> ~[postgresql-42.2.18.jar:42.2.18]
> at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:323)
> ~[postgresql-42.2.18.jar:42.2.18]
> at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:473)
> ~[postgresql-42.2.18.jar:42.2.18]
> at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:393)
> ~[postgresql-42.2.18.jar:42.2.18]
> at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeWithFlags(PgPreparedStatement.java:164)
> ~[postgresql-42.2.18.jar:42.2.18]
> at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PgPreparedStatement.java:130)
> ~[postgresql-42.2.18.jar:42.2.18]
> at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:61)
> ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar:na]
> at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java)
> ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar:na]
> at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:197)
> ~[hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
> at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3301)
> ~[hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
> at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3828)
> ~[hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
> at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityInsertAction.execute(EntityInsertAction.java:107)
> ~[hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
> at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:604)
> ~[hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
> at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.lambda$executeActions$1(ActionQueue.java:478)
> ~[hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
> at java.util.LinkedHashMap.forEach(LinkedHashMap.java:684) ~[na:1.8.0_232]
> at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:475)
> ~[hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
> at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:348)
> ~[hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
> at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:40)
> ~[hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
> at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:102)
> ~[hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
> at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.doFlush(SessionImpl.java:1362)
> ~[hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
> at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:453)
> ~[hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
> at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flushBeforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:3212)
> ~[hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
> at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:2380)
> ~[hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
> at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(JdbcCoordinatorImpl.java:447)
> ~[hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
> at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.beforeCompletionCallback(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:183)
> ~[hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
> at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.access$300(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:40)
> ~[hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
> at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.commit(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:281)
> ~[hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
> at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:101)
> ~[hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
> at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:562)
> ~[spring-orm-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
> at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:743)
> ~[spring-tx-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
> at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:711)
> ~[spring-tx-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
> at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:654)
> ~[spring-tx-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
> at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:407)
> ~[spring-tx-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
> at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119)
> ~[spring-tx-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
> at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
> ~[spring-aop-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
> at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:749)
> ~[spring-aop-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
> at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:691)
> ~[spring-aop-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
> at com.vargaerik.fishgame.fish.service.FishService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$ef554122.save()
> ~[classes/:na]
> at com.vargaerik.fishgame.fish.controller.FishController.streamFish(FishController.java:33)
> ~[classes/:na]
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_232]
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> ~[na:1.8.0_232]
> at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> ~[na:1.8.0_232]
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_232]
> at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:197)
> ~[spring-web-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
> at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:141)
> ~[spring-web-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:106)
> ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:894)
> ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808)
> ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
> ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1061)
> ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:961)
> ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
> ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898)
> ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
> at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:626)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:4.0.FR]
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
> ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
> at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:4.0.FR]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
> at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
> ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
> at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
> ~[spring-web-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
> at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
> ~[spring-web-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
> at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
> ~[spring-web-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
> at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
> ~[spring-web-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
> at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
> ~[spring-web-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
> at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
> ~[spring-web-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
> [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
> at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542)
> [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:143)
> [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
> at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
> [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
> [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
> at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
> [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
> at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:374)
> [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
> at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
> [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
> at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:888)
> [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
> at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1597)
> [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
> at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
> [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
> [na:1.8.0_232]
> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
> [na:1.8.0_232]
> at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
> [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_232]

Comment: Your table fishes it not being created that is why.  Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33323837/database-application-yml-for-spring-boot-from-applications-properties on how your yaml should look like.

Answer (score 1):

The solution to this problem was pointed out by Susan Mustafa, which was to format the yml file properly, for more details check the comment.

Comment: While this may solve your problem, `ddl-auto: create` shouldn't be used for production-ready environment. You should use schema evolution tools like Liquibase and Flyway instead.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, this is only something I'm doing to get some minor practice with some technologies I'm not familiar with. But I would appreciate if you gave me a brief explanation to why using liquibase or flyway is better for production?

Comment: discussed here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/221379