# Spring Data JPA / Flyway Escaping Double Quotes

Tags: sql, jpa, spring-data-jpa, h2, flyway

I have a spring boot project using Spring Data JPA, Flyway and H2 that is attempting to process a migration script that contains the following SQL statement:

```
ALTER ROLE current_user SET search_path TO "$user", public, my_schema;
```

When Flyway attempts to run this migration, I get the following error:

```
---------------------------------
SQL State  : 42001
Error Code : 42001
Message    : Syntax error in SQL statement "ALTER ROLE[*] CURRENT_USER SET SEARCH_PATH TO ""$user"", PUBLIC, MY_SCHEMA"; expected "TABLE, USER, INDEX, SCHEMA, SEQUENCE, VIEW"; SQL statement:
ALTER ROLE current_user SET search_path TO "$user", public, my_schema [42001-200]
```

It looks like somewhere in the process, the double quotes around `"$user"` got escaped with an additional set of quotes.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `ALTER ROLE` is no valid [h2 Command](http://www.h2database.com/html/commands.html). (and that is also, how the error message sounds like.) I think you mean rather [GRANT ROLE](http://www.h2database.com/html/commands.html#grant_role)!(?)
2. If we need to escape `"`, refer to [quoted names](http://www.h2database.com/html/grammar.html#quoted_name):

> ```txt
> "anything"
> | U&"anything" [ UESCAPE 'anything' ]
> ```
>
> Case of characters in quoted names is preserved as is. Such names can
> contain spaces. The maximum name length is 256 characters. **Two double quotes can be used to create a single double** quote inside an identifier. With default settings identifiers in H2 are case sensitive.

so `"$user"` *should be no problem*.

See also:

- [json data type](http://www.h2database.com/html/grammar.html#json)

Comment: Ah I see now.  "ALTER ROLE" is postgresql-specific.  I was using H2 for tests.  I'll have to find a different way to test this.

Comment: thx for accept! :-) ... [from flyway](https://flywaydb.org/blog/a-simple-way-to-manage-multi-environment-deployments), [spring-boot-specific](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33323837/592355) ;(;(;(